# Upload package to testflight ERROR ITMS-90125

Tags: swift, itmstransporter

ERROR ITMS-90125: The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker.

Answer (score 0):

I seem solved this error by renaming it.
I use cocoapods, and has a local pod named "ModuleXXX".
It seems that Apple does not support framework naming prefix like "Module".